# Rails Searching Across Multiple Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have a Project model which has many UserStories. What I want is to let users search at their profile in their Projects by `title`, `description` or `UserStory#name`. I succeeded in searching by `title` and `descripion`. Any help on how to make the searching by `UserStory#name` work?

This is my form in `views/profile/index`:

```
<%= form_tag "profile/", :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search"%>
<% end %>
```

And here is my `index` action in profile/controller:

```
def index   
  if params[:search]    
    @projects = current_user.projects
                  .where( 'title LIKE ? or description LIKE ?',
                          "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%" )

    current_user.projects.each do |project|
      if (project.user_stories)
        project.user_stories.each do |story|
          if story.name.include? params[:search]
            @projects << story.project
          end
        end
      end
    end

    @projects = @projects.page(params[:page]).per_page(4)
  else
    @projects = current_user.projects.order("title")
                  .page(params[:page]).per_page(4)
  end       
end
```

Comment: In what way does it not work now, error message or just not the data you're after?

Comment: If the record doesn't exists in the data base it gives an error massege "The action 'show' could not be found for ProfileController", that is in project title or description searching but in the user story name searching it always doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

infused has it right; you can do this in one query. You can also do a lot to simplify your code.

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    values = { search: "%#{ params[:search] }%" }

    conditions = %q{ projects.title          LIKE :search
                     OR projects.description LIKE :search
                     OR user_stories.name    LIKE :search }

    @projects = current_user.projects.joins(:user_stories)
                  .where(conditions, values)
  else
    @projects = current_user.projects.order(:title)
  end      

  @projects = @projects.page(params[:page]).per_page(4) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the other table in the query and then add conditions in the where clause:

```
s = "%#{params[:search]}%"
current_user.projects.includes(:user_stories).where('title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR user_stories.name LIKE ?', s, s, s)
```

Comment: It gives that error       SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user_stories.name: SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "project_user_relations" ON "projects"."id" = "project_user_relations"."project_id" WHERE "project_user_relations"."user_id" = ? AND (title LIKE '%project title%' OR description LIKE '%project title%' OR user_stories.name LIKE '%project title%')  ORDER BY title LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0